# Dividing total sum of one column by the total sum of another column - SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns. They are labeled NAME, BRAND and SALES. NAME is varchar, BRAND is varchar and Sales is number.

I want to query the results of dividing the name column by the total sales of the brand column and create a 4th column with the alias "Dollar Share"

There are over 900 rows, so throwing them into Excel and doing it manually is hair-pulling. For example I have:
BEER SALES

```
NAME          BRAND           SALES
BUD 6 PK      BUD              5000
BUD 24 PK     BUD              4000
BUD 12 PK     BUD              3000
```

I want the results to say

```
NAME          BRAND           SALES       PERCENTAGE
BUD           BUD             5000       0.41666667
```

How can I write a query to encapsulate all of this? I am so lost.

Comment: Shouldn't BUD sales be 12000? And add Heineken or some other beer to you sample data, to make things clearer.

Comment: Please post an attempt at writing the query.

Comment: `select brand as name, brand, max(sales) as sales, sales/sum(sales) over (partition by brand)  as percentage from x group by name, brand` might be close but bud as a name has me perplexed since there is no such name in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
create table Sales(name varchar(100), Brand varchar(100), Sales int)
insert into Sales(Name,Brand,Sales)
values 
('BUD 6 PK','BUD',5000),
('BUD 24 PK','BUD',4000),
('BUD 12 PK','BUD',3000)

    select Name, 
           Brand, 
           Sales, 
           cast(Sales as float)/sum(sales) over (partition by brand)  PercentageOfBrandSales
    from Sales
```